# Angular: When to put a variable inside curly braces?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

When I use a variable in the view (HTML), when should I put it inside curly braces `{{}}`?

I saw an example like this where an `img` tag has two directives with the same value, but the first (`ng-src`) variable should be in curly braces and the second (`ng-show`) variable doesn't.

```js
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', $scope => {
  $scope.img = 'https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/852ac41bdb5200059504e6e9ce6fc5ea1516289808_medium.png';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-show="img">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check the documentation. If the documentation says that the directive take an expression, avoid using using interpolation `{{ }}`. In the case of `ng-src`, the documentaion explicitly says use `{{ }}`. If the attribute is not an AngularJS directive, use interpolation.

Comment: Very helpful.
Thank you @georgeawg